# How to pull image from a private repository using containerd?

Tags: containerd, containerdctl

How to pull images from a private repository using containerd?

I using the below containerd command to pull an image from a private repository, but it's failing with the below error message.

```
sudo crictl pull qtech/graphql:latest

FATA[0002] pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/qtech/graphql:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/qtech/graphql:latest": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I did log in using my docker credentials and pulled the same image with success.

```
azureuser@zk-master:~$ sudo docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: qtech
Password: 
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded


azureuser@zk-master:~$ sudo docker pull qtech/graphql:latest
latest: Pulling from qtech/graphql
40e059520d19: Pull complete 
e640ca4424de: Pull complete 
3ee146eff338: Pull complete 
7a51ccd0399b: Pull complete 
c49798e0169e: Pull complete 
519f1a159b82: Pull complete 
6200637fe07c: Pull complete 
5789d71f6f43: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:186ba59f4d3ccb03fd84888fc33aa12a8854f23e566c6e5a870ef7a43c3fb1f1
Status: Downloaded newer image for qtech/graphql:latest
docker.io/qtech/graphql:latest
azureuser@zk-master:~$
```

But containerd seems to be not picking up those credentials during run time.

So how to pull images from a private repository using containerd?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

*crictl pull --creds "UserName:Password" "image details from private registry@SHA details"*

Comment: did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to be able to access from kubernetes, you need to add this:

1- Create Kubernetes Secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry registry-credential --docker-server=docker.io --docker-username=<your-username-of-your-private-registry> --docker-password=<your-password-of-your-private-registry> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

2- Modify default service account:

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts default -o yaml > ./service-account.yaml 

vim ./service-account.yaml



apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2015-08-07T22:02:39Z
  name: default
  namespace: default
  uid: 052fb0f4-3d50-11e5-b066-42010af0d7b6
secrets:
- name: default-token-uudge
imagePullSecrets:
- name: registry-credential
```

Next:

```
kubectl replace serviceaccount default -f ./service-account.yaml
```

In this way, Kubernetes already has the credentials for specifically this registry.

for example, if you add this:

```
mkdir -p /etc/containerd/certs.d/_default
vim /etc/containerd/certs.d/_default/hosts.toml

server = "https://<your-registry-server>"

[host."https://<your-registry-server>"]
  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve", push]
  skip_verify = true # this is optional
```

Now modify the containerd conf

```
 vim /etc/containerd/config.toml

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
...
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
    config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

Afer restart containerd

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

After of this you can use:

```
kubectl run NAME --image=qtech/graphql:latest
```